# I want to add category to Class class in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c

I made this method

```
-(NSMutableArray *)getProperties:(id)c
{
    NSString *propertyName;
    unsigned int outCount, i;
    NSMutableArray *propertieNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: nil];

    objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList(c, &outCount);
    for (i = 0; i < outCount; i++) {
        objc_property_t property = properties[i];
        propertyName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:property_getName(property)];
        [propertieNames addObject:propertyName];
    }
    return propertieNames;
}
```

I use this

```
NSMutableArray *propertiesNames = [self getProperties:[self class]];
```

I want to use this

```
NSMutableArray *propertiesNames = [[self class] getProperties];
```

How to add category to Class class.　maybe Class class is not Object....

I try add category to Class

```
#import "Class+SN.h"

@implementation Class (SN)

@end
```

I got error

```
Cannot find interface declaration for 'Class'
```

Comment: You are probably better off adding this as a category on `NSObject`, although a handful of classes don't inherit from `NSObject`.  Also, as @tc says you want a class method (`+`) rather than an instance method (`-`).

Comment: 私は非常に残念だけど、StackOverflowのは英語のみです。(I'm very sorry, but english is required on StackOverflow).

Comment: I edit this post only English. thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a class method, you have to use `+` instead of `-`. In class methods, `self` refers to the class, so you can replace `c` with `self`. The documentation for [`class_copyPropertyList`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001418-CH1g-SW45) says that you need to free the list later with `free()`, otherwise you are leaking memory.

```
+ (NSArray *) getProperties
{
    NSString *propertyName;
    unsigned int outCount, i;
    NSMutableArray *propertyNames = [NSMutableArray array];

    objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList(self, &outCount);
    for (i = 0; i < outCount; i++)
    {
        objc_property_t property = properties[i];
        propertyName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:property_getName(property)];
        [propertyNames addObject:propertyName];
    }

    free(properties);

    return propertyNames;
}
```

Also, Objective-C method names rarely use `get`. Many methods with `get` in the name imply that they have output parameters or that the caller should provide their own buffer (for examples of when to use `get` in the name, see [`getCharacters:range:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-getCharacters_range_), and also [`getStreamsToHost:port:inputStream:outputStream:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSStream_Class/Reference/Reference.html)). This convention means your method would be more appropriately named `properties` or `classProperties` etc.

Comment: Thank you. I add the method to NSObject category. and I can call this. [[self class] classProperties]. oh, I changed the method name, as your advice. and add free(). thank you.